# Problem with Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I am creating a keyboard layout for my Dad (Yeah I gave him Linux!)

On windows he used [this one](http://russisch.urz.uni-leipzig.de/key2000.htm)
(The first one "Russisch für Deutsche, empfohlen" (translated: "Russian for German users, recommended"))

Normal letters are working but <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> don't work.

Then <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd>keys are swapped with
<kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, and <kbd>⇑Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

The keys <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>9</kbd> are working normally...

---

This is my Layout File:

```
xkb_symbols "typewriter"
{
    name[Group1] = "Russian (typewriter)";
    key <AB01> { [  Cyrillic_yeru,  Cyrillic_YERU                                 ] };
    key <AB02> { [    Cyrillic_ha,    Cyrillic_HA                                 ] };
    key <AB03> { [   Cyrillic_che,   Cyrillic_CHE                                 ] };
    key <AB04> { [ Cyrillic_softsign, Cyrillic_SOFTSIGN                                 ] };
    key <AB05> { [    Cyrillic_be,    Cyrillic_BE                                 ] };
    key <AB06> { [    Cyrillic_en,    Cyrillic_EN                                 ] };
    key <AB07> { [    Cyrillic_em,    Cyrillic_EM                                 ] };
    key <AB08> { [ Armenian_comma,      semicolon                                 ] };
    key <AB09> { [ Armenian_mijaket,          colon                                 ] };
    key <AB10> { [    KP_Subtract,       underbar                                 ] };
    key <AC01> { [     Cyrillic_a,     Cyrillic_A                                 ] };
    key <AC02> { [    Cyrillic_es,    Cyrillic_ES                                 ] };
    key <AC03> { [    Cyrillic_de,    Cyrillic_DE                                 ] };
    key <AC04> { [    Cyrillic_ef,    Cyrillic_EF                                 ] };
    key <AC05> { [   Cyrillic_ghe,   Cyrillic_GHE                                 ] };
    key <AC06> { [   Cyrillic_zhe,   Cyrillic_ZHE                                 ] };
    key <AC07> { [ Cyrillic_shorti, Cyrillic_SHORTI                                 ] };
    key <AC08> { [    Cyrillic_ka,    Cyrillic_KA                                 ] };
    key <AC09> { [    Cyrillic_el,    Cyrillic_EL                                 ] };
    key <AC10> { [    Cyrillic_io,    Cyrillic_IO                                 ] };
    key <AC11> { [     Cyrillic_e,     Cyrillic_E                                 ] };
    key <AD01> { [ Cyrillic_shcha, Cyrillic_SHCHA                                 ] };
    key <AD02> { [    Cyrillic_ve,    Cyrillic_VE                                 ] };
    key <AD03> { [    Cyrillic_ie,    Cyrillic_IE                                 ] };
    key <AD04> { [    Cyrillic_er,    Cyrillic_ER                                 ] };
    key <AD05> { [    Cyrillic_te,    Cyrillic_TE                                 ] };
    key <AD06> { [   Cyrillic_tse,   Cyrillic_TSE                                 ] };
    key <AD07> { [     Cyrillic_u,     Cyrillic_U                                 ] };
    key <AD08> { [     Cyrillic_i,     Cyrillic_I                                 ] };
    key <AD09> { [     Cyrillic_o,     Cyrillic_O                                 ] };
    key <AD10> { [    Cyrillic_pe,    Cyrillic_PE                                 ] };
    key <AD11> { [    Cyrillic_yu,    Cyrillic_YU                                 ] };
    key <AD12> { [   Cyrillic_sha,   Cyrillic_SHA                                 ] };
    key <AE01> { [           KP_1,         exclam                                 ] };
    key <AE02> { [           KP_2,       quotedbl                                 ] };
    key <AE03> { [           KP_3, Armenian_section_sign                                 ] };
    key <AE04> { [           KP_4,         dollar                                 ] };
    key <AE05> { [           KP_5,        percent                                 ] };
    key <AE06> { [           KP_6,      ampersand                                 ] };
    key <AE07> { [           KP_7,      KP_Divide                                 ] };
    key <AE08> { [           KP_8, Armenian_parenleft                                 ] };
    key <AE09> { [           KP_9, Armenian_parenright                                 ] };
    key <AE10> { [           KP_0,       KP_Equal                                 ] };
    key <AE11> { [         KP_Add,       question                                 ] };
    key <AE12> { [ Armenian_comma,      quoteleft                                 ] };
    key <BKSL> { [ Cyrillic_hardsign, Cyrillic_HARDSIGN                                 ] };
    key <LSGT> { [    Cyrillic_ze,    Cyrillic_ZE                                 ] };
    key <TLDE> { [    Cyrillic_ya,    Cyrillic_YA                                 ] };
};
```

I still have this Problem, please help.

Comment: Please either insert the layout file directly into the question (using code formatting) or use a pastebin service instead of dropbox. The way you published the file, others first have to login, and then have to download the file, before opening it.

Comment: Guys, could someone help me please.